# Unexpected result from Flatten

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following three evaluations involving `Flatten`:

```
Flatten[f[f[f[x, y], 1, 2], f[x, y]], Infinity, f]
```

> f[x, y, 1, 2, x, y] (* as expected *)

```
Flatten[List[f[f[x, y], 1, 2], f[x, y]], Infinity, f]
```

> {x, y, 1, 2, x, y} (* as expected *)

```
Flatten[List[List[f[x, y], 1, 2], f[x, y]], Infinity, f]
```

> {{f[x, y], 1, 2}, x, y} (* expected {{x, y, 1, 2}, x, y} *)

I would like to know why my expectation was wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Flatten` does not flatten the heads you indicate using the third optional argument, inside other heads. This is true for both the head `List` and other heads. In particular, 
the following does not come as a surprise:

```
Flatten[{f[{{1,2}}],f[{{3,4}}]}]

(*   {f[{{1,2}}],f[{{3,4}}]}  *)
```

Flattening starts at level 1, not level 0, which is why you got your first and second example working. In the last example, the `List` head "stops" `Flatten` from flattening `f` inside lists, but the second part, being on level 1, is flattened all right.

This design is surely intentional. If you need to flatten inside other heads, this can be easily achieved by using replacement rules. I recommend reading [this thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Dec/msg00075.html), which contains answers describing this issue and possible solutions in more detail.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. The _Mathematica_ documentation on `Flatten` is very sparse. I could not anticipate this behavior from the documentation.

Comment: @m_goldberg Was glad to help, and thanks for the accept.