# What is wrong with my use of Flatten?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

Why does

```
Flatten[f[g[a, f[b]], f[c, d]]]
```

result in

> ```
> f[g[a, f[b]], c, d]
> ```

I expected the answer to be

> ```
> f[g[a, b], c, d]
> ```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: See the third entry under the details for `Flatten` in the documentation: Since the head is `f`, only those *subexpressions* of it that are *also* `f` get flattened.

Comment: Related question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16586/3066)

Comment: Thank you! I think i know what the reason is.the hyperlink let me enlightened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compare:

```
Flatten[f[g[a, f[b]], f[c, d]]]

(* f[g[a, f[b]], c, d] *)

Flatten[k[g[a, f[b]], f[c, d]]]

(* k[g[a, f[b]], f[c, d]] *)
```

Note the second does... nothing. That's because `Flatten` looks at the head of the expression (`f` and `k` respectively above), and only flattens *subexpressions* within *with the same head*.

You can see this described in the details section, etc. for the `Flatten` function.

Comment: +1 as you actually answer the question and provide illustration...congratulations on >10K btw

Comment: Suddenly understand ,I misunderstand the meaning in the document

Answer (score 5):

This does not answer your question about `Flatten`. However, rasher's comment does. Here are some approaches to achieve your goal:

```
f[f[g[a, f[b]], f[c, d]] /. f -> Sequence]
```

or

```
# /. f -> Sequence & /@ f[g[a, f[b]], f[c, d]]
```

Comment: Bases covered! +1

Comment: Excellent! This is what I want,thank you!